# Where does PHP-XCache save its data?

Tags: php, linux, apache2, xcache

I've recently installed PHP-XCache and set it up. I can also see files being cached in the admin panel.

But something I do not understand is, where does it save all the data?
Is it stored in a specific location or is it stored in an apache processes memory, if its stored in apaches memory, why does it not need to recompile for every process?

Please help me understand this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP opcode accelerators save to [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory). Shared memory can be accessed by all processes.

Comment: So, will shared memory actually show up somewhere, like residentual memory of some process, or buffers or cache in linuxes memory statistics?

Comment: It will counter towards apache memory (if you are using apache) however it will be a discrete value for all processes, meaning if you have 10 processes and you are using 10MB cache you will use 10MB cache across all.

Comment: Then, if xcache sais, it cached some megabytes of data, but `free` tells me there are 0 bytes of `shared` consumed, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You would see the memory of the apache process grow. I don't have access to a linux box right now but you should see it in top.

Answer (score 1):

It is cached in the memory, and it can't be changed to a place on the hard drive, if you were wondering. There's more info at the link below.

Link: http://forum.lighttpd.net/topic/100804